# Symfony: AuthenticateToken Function skips thrown Exception

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, exception

I have an `ApiKeyAuthenticator` in which my functions is

```
public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
{ 
    $username = $userProvider->getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey);
    if (!$username) {
        dump("xxxxxx");
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
            sprintf('API Key "%s" does not exist.', $apiKey)
        );
    }
}
```

So if there is no `$user` an Exception should be thrown (I tested it with the dump).
But I get this exception:

[image]

Thats really strange, and when I have a look in my Logs in Symfony, I see that the Stack does not stop by my wanted `CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException` and goes on to the `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException`.

[image]

Can someone explain me, whats wrong here?

Comment: What will be return $username?

Comment: The return of $username is NULL

Comment: so, dump is called. right?

Comment: Yes dump is called. See my edited screenshot please, in the log you can see that my wanted Exception is called but the stack does not stop at this point.

Comment: can you paste CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException file?

Comment: The file is in the symfony core bundle: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5638d6adcc95a0bdc757e70d10c1ad3c9d76f62b/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException.php